Why does blender check for a ton of non-existen directories?
I opened a file on the command line on Linux and Blender started checking a ton of non-existing directories. Here's a part of the log:
Read prefs: /home/simone/.config/blender/3.4/config/userpref.blend
Read blend: /home/simone/uv_experiments/warp_question.blend
/boot/efi/ non-existent directory
/dev/fd/17/ non-existent directory
/etc/cups/ssl/ non-existent directory
/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/ non-existent directory
/etc/ssl/private/ non-existent directory
/home/_simone/github/blender/release/datafiles/preview.blend/ non-existent directory
/home/_simone/github/blender/release/datafiles/preview_grease_pencil.blend/ non-existent directory
/home/_simone/github/blender/release/datafiles/startup.blend/ non-existent directory
/home/_simone/github/blender/release/scripts/startup/bl_app_templates_system/2D_Animation/startup.blend/ non-existent directory
/home/_simone/github/blender/release/scripts/startup/bl_app_templates_system/Sculpting/startup.blend/ non-existent directory
/home/_simone/github/blender/release/scripts/startup/bl_app_templates_system/VFX/startup.blend/ non-existent directory
/home/_simone/github/blender/release/scripts/startup/bl_app_templates_system/Video_Editing/startup.blend/ non-existent directory
/home/_simone/github/BlendSCAD/config/startup.blend/ non-existent directory
/home/_simone/github/BlendSCAD/config/userpref.blend/ non-existent directory
/home/_simone/github/boundary-first-flattening/foo.blend/ non-existent directory
/home/_simone/github/boundary-first-flattening/shoe_parts_for_unwrapping.blend/ non-existent directory
/home/_simone/github/DazToBlender/Blender/appdata_common/Blender Foundation/Blender/BLENDER_VERSION/scripts/addons/DTB/dependencies/link_library.blend/ non-existent directory
/home/_simone/github/SketchFabShowAndHide/uploads/001_microtus_agrestis.blend/ non-existent directory
/home/_simone/github/SketchFabShowAndHide/uploads/006_ursus_arctos.blend/ non-existent directory
/home/_simone/github/SubstanceBridge/samples/furnitur.blend/ non-existent directory
/home/lost+found/ non-existent directory
/home/simone/.cache/.fr-vCq80b/HSL_nodes.blend/ non-existent directory
/home/simone/.config/blender/2.82/config/userpref.blend/ non-existent directory
/home/simone/.config/blender/2.92/config/userpref.blend/ non-existent directory
/home/simone/.config/blender/2.92/scripts/addons/blenderkit/blendfiles/cleaned.blend/ non-existent directory
/home/simone/.config/blender/2.92/scripts/addons/blenderkit/blendfiles/material_thumbnailer_cycles.blend/ non-existent directory
/home/simone/.config/blender/2.92/scripts/addons/blenderkit/blendfiles/thumbnailer.blend/ non-existent directory
/home/simone/.config/blender/2.93/config/userpref.blend/ non-existent directory
/home/simone/.config/blender/3.0/config/userpref.blend/ non-existent directory
/home/simone/.config/blender/3.0/scripts/addons/BlenderMalt/.MaltPath/Malt/Pipelines/NPR_Pipeline/Defaults/defaults.blend/ non-existent directory
/home/simone/.config/blender/3.0/scripts/addons/MB-Lab-1_7_8/data/face_rig/face_rig_lib.blend/ non-existent directory
/home/simone/.config/blender/3.0/scripts/addons/MB-Lab-1_7_8/data/face_rig/facial_rig.blend/ non-existent directory
/home/simone/.config/blender/3.0/scripts/addons/MB-Lab-1_7_8/data/humanoid_library.blend/ non-existent directory
/home/simone/.config/blender/3.1/config/userpref.blend/ non-existent directory
/home/simone/.config/blender/3.1/scripts/addons/BlenderMalt/.MaltPath/Malt/Pipelines/NPR_Pipeline/Defaults/defaults.blend/ non-existent directory
/home/simone/.config/blender/3.2/config/userpref.blend/ non-existent directory
/home/simone/.config/blender/3.4/config/userpref.blend/ non-existent directory
/home/simone/.config/blender/3.5/config/userpref.blend/ non-existent directory
/home/simone/.config/blender/3.5/scripts/addons/BlenderMalt/.MaltPath/Malt/Pipelines/NPR_Pipeline/Defaults/defaults.blend/ non-existent directory
/home/simone/.local/share/podman-static/share/containers/storage/overlay/8b45dbd81526ace47db4b00939d222d762a2e7263cecceee906362755578e136/work/work/ non-existent directory

This does not seem to happen with other files.
Peculiarities of the file:

it's probably been created with a later version of Blender (3.5 vs. 3.4)
it's been saved and updated on Windows and Mac before landing on Linnux


Well each path should give a hint at what it is looking for. There seem to be missing scripts, addons, configs, and lots of linked or library blend files, including Manuel Bastioni characters and rigs.  You can check the Outliner in Orphaned Data mode for cleanup, and in DataAPI for diagnostics

I'm very curious about why it logs/boot/efi/? I think it is something related to python, not Blender. I suppose, an add-on may check folders.
